# Trouble with Internationalization on CakePHP 2.0

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-2.0

The internationalization process is not working.

I ran `cake i18n export`. After that I put the translations into the file ".po" in the folder `app/locale/por/LC_MESSAGES/default.po.`.

I called the method `beforeFilter()` in the AppController `Configure::write('Config.language', 'por');`.

But the translation isn't shown in `__()`-methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some possible suggestions:

• Clear the Cake cache in `PATH_YOUR_APP/tmp/cache`. Delete the files    in `models` and `persistent`, but not the directories itself. I believe persistent is where the localised strings are saved, but empty both to be sure.

• Do you    override the `beforeFilter` in any of your controllers, other than    the `AppController`? If so call `parent::beforeFilter();` in the    controller's `beforeFilter` method, before processing other stuff, like so:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
  parent:beforeFilter();
  //Do stuff here
}
```

• How did you create the translation files? Is there a `.mo` file in the `.po` directory as well? I believe directly editing `.po` and `.pot` files is not recommended due to character encoding issues (but I could be mistaken). [Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/)  is a good tool for manipulating `.po` files, though it could be more robust.

Answer (score 0):

Some more things to check

1. Check whether your browser's language is selected properly Portuguese as the first language of choice
2. Is your msgid and msgstr keys in individual lines and properly enclosed the text within double quotes?
3. I'm not a CakePHP expert, but try moving the configuration to the bootstrap.php. Your code seems logical there.

Comment: I also tried the bootstrap, but the problem was the cache ... But thanks!