# Localizing timeAgoInWords in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, localization, internationalization, cakephp-2.0, timeago

In my CakePHP application,
By using cake.bat i created POT files and by using PoEdit I created PO files.
So by writing **__('myword')** i can see localized word in my application successfully.

But now I need to localize "timeAgoInWords".
When i run **cake i18n extract**, script didn't get the **_dn()** words in **CakeTime**
http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/cake-time#line-522

So i created a **dummy.ctp** file and copy-pasted contents from cake-time file to dummy file.
I run cake script and POEdit again. And it created instances like below, into the file **app/Locale/tur/LC_MESSAGES/default.po**

```
#: View\App\dummy.ctp:30;33
msgid "%d minute"
msgid_plural "%d minutes"
msgstr[0] "%d dakika"
msgstr[1] "%d dakika"
```

In core.php i already set default language to Turkish:

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'tur');
```

But when i check my application, results of **timeAgoInWords** came in English.

How can i fix this

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954199/trouble-with-internationalization-on-cakephp-2-0?rq=1   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722716/cakephp-automating-i18n-extract-shell-process-from-batch-file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cake's messages are extracted into a different domain, in this case, the `cake` domain. This means that cake messages will not be extracted into your `default.pot` file, but will go into `cake.pot` file.

Curiously, cake.pot doesn't seem to be included in the download, nor does the i18n shell allow you to pass a param to include the cake core during extraction. However, it is still easily done (my comments start with a `#`):

```
$:/var/www/path/app$ cake i18n extract

# if will ask you here if you want to extract from your app folder
# simply press enter to confirm
What is the path you would like to extract?
[Q]uit [D]one  
[/var/www/path/app/]

# now it will ask you again, in this case enter the cake path
What is the path you would like to extract?
[Q]uit [D]one  
[D] > /var/www/path/lib/Cake

# third time, just press enter
What is the path you would like to extract?
[Q]uit [D]one  
[D] > 

# press enter to accept the app/Locale
What is the path you would like to output?
[Q]uit  
[/var/www/path/app//Locale] > 

# press enter to keep translation domains deparate
Would you like to merge all domains strings into the default.pot file? (y/n) 
[n] >
```

Now wait for the extraction to finish and enjoy the pain of translating ;)