# CakePHP 2.4 and Timehelper's timeAgoInWords locale

Tags: cakephp, datetime, localization, cakephp-2.4

Recently I updated CakePHP from 2.3.9 to 2.4.4. As far as I remember (I can't test now) `Timehelper::timeAgoInWords` was working well in old CakePHP. But after this update I get locale problem. I change language to English, but time ago still comes in Turkish.

In `core.php` i already set default language to Turkish:

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'tur');
```

Inside my view file I use this:

```
$d = "2012-05-02 20:17:30"
$myString = $this->Time->timeAgoInWords($d, array('end' => '+10 year'));
```

I get result in Turkish like this:

```
1 yıl, 8 ay, 4 hafta önce
```

I want result like this:

```
1 year, 8 months, 4 weeks ago
```

My session variables like this:

```
[Config] => Array
        (
            [userAgent] => 35db889a82essb4e57b540d52e8a766d
            [time] => 1391121684
            [countdown] => 10
            [language] => eng
        )
```

Although I set my language as English, result cames in Turkish. How can I debug/fix this ?

**Edit:**
I checked for Configure-language values. Results like this:

```
echo Configure::read( 'Config.language' );
result: tur
```

But

```
echo $this->Session->read('Config.language');
result: eng
```

As I noted in the top of my question, I already setted Configure::language inside my `core.php` file. Does `core.php` overrides my session value ?

**Edit2:**
And strange thing is, although Config.language looks like both "tur" and "eng", other parts inside my view file works well. For example this works well:

```
__("string")
```

**Edit3:**
Regarding to this page: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html

I added this:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public function beforeFilter() {
        if ($this->Session->check('Config.language')) {
            Configure::write('Config.language', $this->Session->read('Config.language'));
        }
    }
}
```

After this change config language results like this:

```
echo Configure::read( 'Config.language' );
result: eng

echo $this->Session->read('Config.language');
result: eng
```

But I still see timeAgo result in Turkish..
Last week I migrated to new server, maybe some setting is missing for English or etc ? I can't understand why `timeAgo` doesn't work while `__("string")` works.

**Edit4:**
I even changed `core.php` like this:

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'eng');
setlocale( LC_TIME, 'en_US.utf8', 'eng', 'en', 'en_US', 'en_UK' );
```

It seems like, in my configuration nothing changes `timeAgoInWords`'s language. I override in every beforeFilter to change Config.language is to english, but still words are Turkish. Note that in my `php.ini` timezone is like this:

```
date.timezone = Europe/Istanbul
```

**Edit5:**
It seems like there is a problem in the translations. I checked for source code of timeago, here is a copy: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.4/lib/Cake/Utility/CakeTime.php#L738

It seems like this method uses __d and __dn so I checked the results in my code. "az önce" means "just now" in Turkish.

I'm sure that Config.language is "eng". So:

```
echo __d('cake', 'just now', 'just now'); // results: "az önce"
echo __('just now');                      // results: "just now"
echo __('az önce');                       // results: "az önce"
$days=12; 
echo __dn('cake', '%d day', '%d days', $days, $days); // results: "12 gün"
echo __('gün');                       // results: "days"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I change current language like this:

```
$this->Session->write('Config.language', $lang);
```

I set default language like this in every request in `core.php`:

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'tur');
```

Regarding to [CakePHP documents](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#localization-in-cakephp) I must add this code to my AppController:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public function beforeFilter() {
        if ($this->Session->check('Config.language')) {
            Configure::write('Config.language', $this->Session->read('Config.language'));
        }
    }
}
```

After adding the code above to beforeFilter() of AppController, I refreshed `/tmp/cache/persistent/` folder and everything works fine.

**Edit:**
This solution worked well for english but it didn't work for other languages.
Why ? As noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402330/localizing-timeagoinwords-in-cakephp) cake looks for `cake.po` files inside your Locale folder.
For example if you want to see cake's messages in french, so you need to create this file:

```
/app/Locale/fra/LC_MESSAGES/cake.po
```

---

Where do CakePHP use cake.po records ?
For example: [this method](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6/lib/Cake/Utility/CakeTime.php#L409)

---

You can create default po files like this: [i18n shell tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/i18n-shell.html)
After shell's file creation, you can edit cake.po file for your language.

---

For some languages cake.po files are ready. For example: [french file](https://github.com/cakephp/localized/blob/master/Locale/fra/LC_MESSAGES/cake.po)
You can find rest from there: https://github.com/cakephp/localized

Answer (score 1):

To debug `echo Configure::read( 'Config.language' );` **right before** your `timeAgo` call. If you find it's not "eng" then you are setting the language to English *after* timeAgo was already called.

IF that does not work then you may have to call setlocale as well

I use this for english dates:

`setlocale( LC_TIME, 'en_US.utf8', 'eng', 'en', 'en_US', 'en_UK' );`

And I guess this would the call for Turkish

`setlocale(LC_TIME, 'tr_TR.UTF-8', 'tr_TR', 'tr', 'turkish');`

PS: Looking at the history of the TimeHelper nothing was changed to affect the locale, but may a dependency was changed.

Comment: Thank you Ilie, just before timeAgo I checked for Config.language. I get both english and Turkish. I added results to the end of question.

Comment: OK, in your before filter replace your code with just simply this: `Configure::write( 'Config.language', 'eng')` to force English every where and check how timeAgo() behaves. If it works, then somewhere in your code you are switching to Turkish.

Comment: I added `Configure::write( 'Config.language', 'eng')` to beforeFilters of controllers. I even wrote it just before the `timeAgoInWords` line inside my view files. When I check I can see that Config.language is set to "eng".

Comment: When I write strings this works: `__("word")`. But `timeAgoInWords` still showed in Turkish.

Comment: Try this as well `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'tr_TR.UTF-8', 'tr_TR', 'tr', 'turkish');` (before your timeAgo call). Maybe timeAgo looks at system locale to translated your string.

Answer (score 0):

For Russian language it`s necessary to set cake.po file encoding to utf-8, or you will see blank options instead of translated month names.

My solution is: 
1. Place file cake.po in \app\Locale\rus\LC_MESSAGES directory and set
2. in AppController file

```
public function beforeFilter()
    {
        Configure::write('Config.language', 'rus');
    }
```

Translation file for your language you can find in files of CakePHP Localized plugin https://github.com/cakephp/localized